# Check one array's elements contains in another array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

**

```
labels = ['UNREAD', 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL', 'INBOX']
incomingLabels = ['UNREAD','IMPORTANT' 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL', 'INBOX']
```

**

`labels array` is static array. How do I check `incoming array` contains all elemnts of `labels array`.

My attempts

```
intersectionOfTwoArrays = list(set(incomingLabels) & set(labels))
if np.array_equal(labels, intersectionOfTwoArrays): 
   //Do somthing
```

that attempt not succed because `intersectionOfTwoArrays's` not ordered same as `labels array`

Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: What do you mean by *not ordered same as labels array*?

Comment: labels = ['UNREAD', 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL', 'INBOX']
intersectionOfTwoArrays =  ['UNREAD', 'INBOX','CATEGORY_PERSONAL'] because of that if condition fails

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean, what does the order have to do with what you are trying to do?

Comment: check arrays are quals or not

Comment: You mean `set(incomingLabels) >= set(labels)`? array_equal does an elementwise comparison. Are you actually using numpy arrays?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

convert both list into set before doing array_equal to avoid order issue

```
labels = ['UNREAD', 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL', 'INBOX']
incomingLabels = ['UNREAD','IMPORTANT', 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL', 'INBOX']
intersectionOfTwoArrays = list(set(incomingLabels) & set(labels))

if np.array_equal(set(labels), set(intersectionOfTwoArrays)): 
    # Do somthing 
    print "match"
```

alternatively, you could using set method issubset

```
labels = ['UNREAD', 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL', 'INBOX']
incomingLabels = ['UNREAD','IMPORTANT', 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL', 'INBOX']

if set(labels).issubset(set(incomingLabels)):
    # issubset true, do something
    print "match"
```